# QLPreviewController not working in iOS 6

Tags: objective-c, ios6, qlpreviewcontroller

In iOS 6 the QLPreviewController no longer loads a PDF from a URL.  It works fine in iOS 5.  I have implemented the QLPreviewControllerDataSource methods as documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewControllerDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009665).

```
#pragma mark - QLPreviewControllerDataSource
- (NSInteger)numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller {
    return 1;
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>) previewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller previewItemAtIndex: (NSInteger) index;
{
    NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.bliley.net/XTAL/PDF_Instructions/Test_File.pdf"];
    return fileURL;
}
```

This works perfectly in iOS 5, however in iOS 6 the console outputs:

```
Couldn't issue file extension for path: /XTAL/PDF_Instructions/Test_File.pdf
```

Comment: Doesn't it actually require using a local file URL? It looks to me like you are using a remote url and it's erroring with everything after the http://host/ portion.

Comment: someone told me that in ios 6 they implemented a stricter check for this method that the url most start with 'file://', but I can't find any documentations on it.  If anyone knows of a reference, please post.

Comment: Did you find a solution?  if so please share it or accept an answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I downloaded the file from remote url and saved locally, then I display the PDF using the QLPreviewController .In iOS 6 its working.

First i saved the file from remote url using the following code :

```
    NSString *local_location;

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"sampleData" ofType:@"plist"];
        path = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    local_location= [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"My_Invoice.pdf"]];
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString: remoteurl]];
        [request setDownloadDestinationPath:local_location];
        [request startSynchronous];
```

For showing the Pdf :

```
QLPreviewController* preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
        preview.dataSource = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:preview animated:YES];
```

QLPreviewController delegate methods are :

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfPreviewItemsInPreviewController: (QLPreviewController *) controller
{
    return 1;
}

- (id <QLPreviewItem>)previewController:(QLPreviewController *)controller previewItemAtIndex:(NSInteger)index
{

    return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:local_location];


}
```

Comment: Just my two cents : you also get the "Couldn't issue file extension for path" error if the file pointed by the URL does not exists. So if you download the file and give then a wrong URL to QLPreviewController you'll get this same error. Why would you do that ? Well silly bugs do happen ...

Comment: @SébastienNussbaumer I didnt get this error in my project. once check your path.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to say that this happened in your project, just that it happened in mine and wanted to let know other readers that checking that the  file exists is a good idea :)

Answer (score 8):

Have you tried using fileURLWithPath instead of URLWithString? I had other issues that were fixed by doing so.

Also not sure if QLPreviewController will handle remote URLs. If not, you could download the file and then display it.

Comment: fileURLWithPath fixed my problem! Thanks!

Comment: I have an application in App Store already. It works fine in iOS 5. But it doesn't work any more. I need to change everything to make it work? What a great "upgrading" by Apple.

Answer (score 4):

I am having a similar issue and seems like it might stem from a stricter enforcement of the file-type URL of QLPreviewItem

```
@property (readonly) NSURL *previewItemURL;
Discussion
This property is used by a Quick Look preview controller to get an item’s URL. In typical use, you would implement a getter method in your preview item class to provide this value.

The value of this property must be a file-type URL.

If the item is not available for preview, this property’s getter method should return nil. In this case, the Quick Look preview controller displays a “loading” view.

Availability
Available in iOS 4.0 and later.
Declared In
QLPreviewItem.h
```

***UPDATE: I have opened a bug with Apple dealing with this issue for iOS 6 and it seems they have aced it as a bug so may offer a fix in the near future.  The bug I opened had to do with using custom NSURLProtocols for the preview, but may apply to other aspects as well.***

[Link to class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewItem_Protocol_iPhoneOS/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/QLPreviewItem)

Comment: Still no update from Apple, but was able to get a work around working using UIWebView and overriding urlprotocol to load the file

Answer (score 0):

But note that QLPreviewController expects a URL to a local resource

You would need to download and save the PDF file locally first and then create a proper file URL to the local file.